# Easy way to process queue with N threads in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a list of account numbers.  Foreach account number I need to call method `ProcessAccount`.  There will be approximately 150,000 accounts that need to be processed and each account could take between .5 to 2 seconds to process.

I'd like to setup threading somehow so I can be processing 4 accounts at a time for example.

Is there a simple pattern I can use for this?

What I'd like to be able to do is start 4 threads processing the first 4 accounts, and then as each individual thread is finished start another thread with the next account until all the accounts have been processed.

Comment: FYI - This will most likely be running from a console application.

Comment: What is the dependency on `ProcessAccount`?  Is this a compute-bound operation or an I/O bound operation?

Comment: Bryan has a good point there, you mention a list, is that a List<Account>? If you need to read data from disk, or call remote services or something things are very different than when you have all the data you need ready in memory. To speed things up you first need to identify your bottleneck

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easy to handle with the TPL (Task Parallel Library).  It would look something like

```
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };
Parallel.ForEach(accounts, options, a =>
{
    ProcessAccount(a);
});
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782721.aspx

Note that the TPL might decide to run less than 4 concurrent threads, but will not run more than 4 based on the specified options.  It might do that, for example, if it determines that the provided lamda (which calls ProcessAccount) is CPU bound and there are less than 4 CPU cores on the system.  Generally, especially in .NET 4.5, the TPL makes very good decisions about the number of threads to use.

As @Servy notes in the comments, unless you have a very specific reason to limit the code to 4 threads, it is best to just let TPL sort out how many threads to use on its own.  That way, if the same code is running on a 128 core processor in the year 2018, long after you move on to other things, it is free to use all 128 cores).

Comment: Unless you wish to intentionally limit the resources consumed to leave them available for others, it's usually best to not specify any more than you need to.  The more freedom that you give the library to do what it thinks is appropriate the better it will perform.

Answer (score 1):

Use PLinq:

```
var accounts = //some 150,000 account numbers
accounts.AsParallel().ForAll(ProcessAccount);
```

or, if other arguments are required, use a lambda expression:

```
accounts.AsParallel().ForAll(account => ProcessAccount(account, argument2, argument3));
```

Comment: @EricJ. no, you're right, it doesn't.  In my experience PLinq does a good enough job of throttling itself without any help from me, but I'm not in extremely performance-sensitive territory.

Comment: @EricJ. My guess is the OP isn't familiar with the concept of a thread pool (and expected to have to make his own with a static number of threads) and doesn't have a business requirement of restricting it to 4 threads.